# using dropit.js inside of an li, causes the list to dissappear after it is collapsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

If you take a dropit dropdown menu, and wrap it in an LI, it dissappears once it is collapsed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
<li>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
        <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Some Action 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some Action 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some Action 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some Action 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
<li>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu').dropit();
});
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/c5zv3of2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's a bug in dropit.

Looking at your fiddle in chrome dev tools, when you click the wrapped dropdown, dropit is adding the "dropit-open" class to the wrapping LI, so you end up with the below html:

```
<li class="dropit-open">
    <ul class="menu dropit">
        <li class="dropit-trigger dropit-open">
        <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropit-submenu" style="">
                <li><a href="#">Some Action 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some Action 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some Action 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some Action 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When you click the menu closed, the following code in dropit.js removes the class and hides the UL instead of just the LI.

```
$(this).parents(settings.triggerParentEl).removeClass('dropit-open').find(settings.submenuEl).hide();
```

This results in the below html. The `style="display: none;"` on the UL is the culprit.

```
<li class="">
    <ul class="menu dropit" style="display: none;">
        <li class="dropit-trigger">
        <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropit-submenu" style="display: none;">
                <li><a href="#">Some Action 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some Action 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some Action 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Some Action 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This is most likely due to a bug in dropit itself.

In fact, dropit has an [open github issue for this scenario](https://github.com/gilbitron/Dropit/issues/15)

#### The Fix

In dropit.js, change

```
$(this).parents(settings.triggerParentEl).removeClass('dropit-open').find(settings.submenuEl).hide();
```

to

```
$('.dropit-open').removeClass('dropit-open').find('.dropit-submenu').hide();
```

This will remove the dropit-open class from all of the LIs but only hide the LIs which are actually under the submenu.